# Word Macro accessing Excel TextToColumns

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro that sorts some text and then opens Excel and pastes it into consecutive cells in a column. This part works fine. I would like to then use TextToColumns to split the cell contents at each tab character, but can't get it to work.

If I run this:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
'a section to insert the data from Word
objWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Range("A:A").Select
objWorkbook.Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
```

I get an error saying Object or Method not found for the last line. I've tried a few different edits that either give the same error, or give no error but don't actually split the text!

Any advice appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Range("A1")` needs to be specified in which workbook and worksheet it is
2. `xlDelimited` does not exist in Word but only in Excel. Therefore you need to define it or use `1` instead.
3. Avoid using `.Select`

The following should work:

```
Const xlDelimited As Long = 1

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
'a section to insert the data from Word
objWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Range("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=objWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
```

Note that you run `TextToColumns` on an empty worksheet right now. So you should paste your data first.

Comment: Thanks... I had tried specifying the Range location before without success, but not xlDelimited. However, I'm still getting an error 438 (Object does not support this property or method) on the last line.

Comment: Actually, I've tried without specifying any properties of TextToColumns and that has worked - I guess all of my settings can be found as default

Comment: @Josh Don't trust the default. It takes as default what ever was used last, there is no default actually. You might want to check the documentation of the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) to get it work with your parameters

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. The end-user probably won't be running alternative operations like this, so it may work for time being at least.
I was working from the documentation originally – I can't see any problem with the properties I was trying to set. I will try adding them in one at a time to see if only one brings the error: if they all do, then I guess the problem is the method of accessing them via the external macro.

Comment: Defining xlDelimited using the Const/As line doesn't work, but if you just enter the numerical value instead of the name ( DataType:=1 ) that does the job! Thanks for the help.